# Kendall correlation is significant but cross correlation is not significant

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, pearson-r, cross-correlation, kendall-tau

I have time series data and I am confused about the output of correlation and cross correlation.

This is my data:

```
      y               x1       
 Min.   :    0   Min.   :23.47  
 1st Qu.:   18   1st Qu.:27.28  
 Median :  751   Median :28.00 
 Mean   : 1601   Mean   :27.99  
 3rd Qu.: 1744   3rd Qu.:28.78  
 Max.   :11692   Max.   :30.78
```

I performed Kendall correlation analysis because the data is not linear. The output is as follows:

```
corr.test(x1,y)

Call:corr.test(x = x1, y = y, method = "kendall")
    Correlation matrix 
[1] -0.22
Sample Size 
[1] 849
These are the unadjusted probability values.
  The probability values  adjusted for multiple tests are in the p.adj object. 
[1] 0

 To see confidence intervals of the correlations, print with the short=FALSE option
```

From what I understood about the output, there is significant correlation between x1 and y.

Then, I also performed cross correlation and the output is as follows:

```
print(ccf(x1, y, lag.max = 14))

Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag

   -14    -13    -12    -11    -10     -9     -8     -7     -6     -5 
-0.052 -0.050 -0.049 -0.059 -0.067 -0.061 -0.043 -0.047 -0.038 -0.031 
    -4     -3     -2     -1      0      1      2      3      4      5 
-0.029 -0.043 -0.043 -0.036 -0.036 -0.035 -0.036 -0.041 -0.045 -0.046 
     6      7      8      9     10     11     12     13     14 
-0.034 -0.031 -0.025 -0.033 -0.038 -0.043 -0.038 -0.031 -0.030
```

[image]

From what I understood about the output, there is no significant correlation between x1 and y at lags and leads of 0-14 days.

**My questions are:**

1. I thought cross-correlation at lag 0 should be significant because the correlation between x1 and y is significant. But in fact cross-correlation at lag 0 is not significant. I thought it should be the same because correlation analysis is testing the lag 0 data. Please correct me if I am wrong.
2. Another thing I suspect about the problem mentioned above is the "method" of correlation. I used Kendall correlation. But cross-correlation is using Pearson's correlation. That's why there is a difference in the significance. Does this make sense? Am I using Kendall correlation correctly in my case?

Comment: The lag 0 cross correlation is linear correlation. If you want to compare it to a correlation you'd compare it to a linear correlation not a nonlinear one. Given you said the relationship was not linear, looking at the CCF seems problematic